# how do i combine and sum two results in sql?

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have one table, let's call it 'TBL'.
i have one column that have only 3 values available.(let's say 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
the values can return multiple times.
for example:

```
TBL
---

Column1
-------
AAA
AAA
BBB
CCC
BBB
CCC
BBB
CCC
AAA
```

i want to create a table result that looks like this:

```
TBL-RESULT
----------
AAA+BBB 60%
CCC     40%
```

i want to show AAA and BBB in one result and there precentage from all values in one line,
and CCC in a second line as well.

the big problem is also that i need to do so in sql of ACCESS (2007).

can someone help me?

thank you,
gady m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume table is called `MyTable` and column is `MyColumn`

```
    select IIF(MyColumn<>'CCC', 'AAA+BBB', 'CCC'), 
     100*count(MyColumn='CCC')/(select count(*) from MyTable) from MyTable
     group by MyColumn='CCC'
```

Comment: hy again, your answer is working grate! but it's seems that i miss something. in that same table i have also empty values that i want to ignore them it's looks something like this: 
MyTable 
------- 
Column1 
------- 
AAA 
AAA
 
BBB 
CCC 
BBB 

CCC 
BBB 
CCC
 
AAA how can i adjust your answer to the new situation? thank you again, gady m

Comment: in my last comment the example doesnt show properly, 
there are empty rows between some values...

Comment: @gadym are your blanks empty strings or nulls?